# How to retrieve http get parameters in link in Laravel?

Tags: php, redirect, input, get, laravel-4

I am redirecting users from one laravel website to another for single authentication.

This is the redirect code in the **website 1**

```
return Redirect::to('http://example.com/login?param1=paramValue');
```

In **website 2**, I'm trying to get value of param1

```
$param1 = Input::get('param1');
```

but get() function is not returning the value.

IF I try **Input::has('param1')** , it returns **false**.

Can someone please guide me on what's going wrong with my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is working fine for me,

```
 $param1 = Input::get('param1');
 return $param1;
```

Just try to update your framework using **composer update**